# Adding letter to align number

Tags: align

To adding a letter to the equation number, I have used the following code

```
\newcounter{defcounter}
\setcounter{defcounter}{0}

\newenvironment{eee}[1]{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\refstepcounter{defcounter}
\renewcommand\theequation{E.#1.\thedefcounter}
\begin{equation}}
{\end{equation}}
```

Now what should I do to expand this code to `align` environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the infrastructure of `subequations`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{eee}[2][equation]
 {\subequations\def\eeecurrent{#1}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{E.#2.\arabic{equation}}%
  \csname #1\endcsname}
 {\csname end\eeecurrent\endcsname
  \endsubequations\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\begin{eee}{one}
a=b
\end{eee}

\begin{eee}[align]{two}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{eee}

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant, after consulting my crystal ball:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newcounter{exnumber}[exercise]

\newenvironment{eee}[1][equation]
 {\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
  \subequations\def\eeecurrent{#1}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{exnumber}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{E.\theexercise.\arabic{equation}}%
  \csname #1\endcsname}
 {\csname end\eeecurrent\endcsname
  \setcounter{exnumber}{\value{equation}}%
  \endsubequations}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\begin{exercise}
Prove the following
\begin{eee}
a=b
\end{eee}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Prove the following
\begin{eee}[align]
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{eee}
and also the following
\begin{eee}[gather]
a=b\\
c=d
\end{eee}
\end{exercise}

\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A nice answer in so many ways.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I want to enumerate `align` automatically. Furthermore, I want to reset the beginning number in each, say, "Exercise". I have done it for `equation` but not for `align`.

Comment: @Immanuel What do you mean by “automatically”? I can answer your question as stated, not read your mind. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Ok! My mistake! Suppose that you have several exercises. In each exercise you want to enumerate the equations, e.g. (E.2.1) ... (E.2.10). For the next exercise you must have (E.3.1) and so forth.

Comment: @Immanuel I consulted my crystal ball and got an idea. If it is not what you have in mind, please open a new question and specify precisely what your needs are.

Comment: @egreg You like and use this phrase with crystal ball very much! That works, but that's not what I'm looking for. It's a little bit complicated for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Immanuel Sorry. But without a full specification, I can't tell you more.